# Mock document.defaultView.ready in returned observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs

I am writing a test for the method **loadScript()**:

```
export class CourseContentElementEmbedTweetService {
  private readonly TWITTER_OBJECT = 'twttr';
  private readonly TWITTER_SCRIPT_ID = 'twitter-wjs';
  private readonly TWITTER_WIDGET_URL = 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
  private readonly document: Document;
 
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document) {
    this.document = document;
  }
 
  getDocumentDefaultView(): Window | null {
    return this.document.defaultView;
  }
 
  loadScript(): Observable<unknown> {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<unknown>) => {
      this.startScriptLoad();
      const documentDefaultView = this.getDocumentDefaultView();
      if (documentDefaultView) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call,@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
        this.document.defaultView[this.TWITTER_OBJECT].ready((twitterData: unknown) => {
          observer.next(twitterData);
          observer.complete();
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

It seems like the following bit of code is flagged as not covered in my report, I'd like to mock the method but I am not sure how to:

```
        this.document.defaultView[this.TWITTER_OBJECT].ready((twitterData: unknown) => {
          observer.next(twitterData);
          observer.complete();
        });
```

So far, I've tried the following:

```
  describe('loadScript()', () => {
    it('should return value from observable', (done: DoneFn) => {
      jest.spyOn(service, 'getTwitterWidgetData').mockImplementation(function () {
        const twitterData: ICourseContentElementEmbedTweetWidgetData = {
          ready: () => {},
          _e: [],
        };
        return twitterData;
      });
      jest.spyOn(service, 'startScriptLoad').mockImplementation(() => {});
      jest.spyOn(service, 'loadScript').mockImplementation(() => of('test'));
      service.loadScript().subscribe((value) => {
        expect(value).not.toBeNull();
        done();
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify the example, I removed some irrelevant code.

Because you use dependency injection, it is easy to test. Create a mock object that conforms to the `Document` interface type, use the [mockFn.mockImplementation(fn)](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) method to mock the `ready` method of the object, and an anonymous callback function is passed in when invoking the `ready` method, we can get this anonymous callback function in `mockImplementation`, call it manually, and pass in mock twitter data. Finally, use the `Observable.subscribe()` method to obtain and assert the value emitted by `observer.next()`.

`service.ts`:

```
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

export class CourseContentElementEmbedTweetService {
  private readonly TWITTER_OBJECT = 'twttr';
  private readonly document;

  constructor(document) {
    this.document = document;
  }

  getDocumentDefaultView() {
    return this.document.defaultView;
  }

  loadScript() {
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<unknown>) => {
      const documentDefaultView = this.getDocumentDefaultView();
      if (documentDefaultView) {
        this.document.defaultView[this.TWITTER_OBJECT].ready((twitterData: unknown) => {
          observer.next(twitterData);
          observer.complete();
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`service.test.ts`:

```
import { CourseContentElementEmbedTweetService } from './service';

describe('69043612', () => {
  test('should pass', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const mTwttierData = 'teresa teng';
    const mDocument = {
      defaultView: {
        twttr: {
          ready: jest.fn().mockImplementation((callback) => {
            callback(mTwttierData);
          }),
        },
      },
    };
    const service = new CourseContentElementEmbedTweetService(mDocument);
    service.loadScript().subscribe((value) => {
      expect(value).toEqual('teresa teng');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/69043612/service.test.ts (9.473 s)
  69043612
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 service.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 18                
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.265 s
```

The uncovered line 18 is `if (documentDefaultView) {}` statement. Nothing to do with the question, don't worry.

Comment: Thanks! Does changing `constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document)` to `constructor(document)` have any implications? I get the error: `S2345: Argument of type '{ defaultView: { twttr: { ready: jest.Mock<any, any>; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Document'.   Type '{ defaultView: { twttr: { ready: Mock<any, any>; }; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Document': URL, alinkColor, all, anchors, and 236 more.` with if I keep `@Inject`.

Comment: I can suppress it with `@ts-ignore` or by doing `const mockedService = new CourseContentElementEmbedTweetService((mockedDocument as unknown) as Document)`

Comment: @methuselah I only created a mocked document that only satisfies the interface with a `ready` method. You can use the TS type to assert `(mDocument as unknown) as Document`. But if you can create a document instance from a factory function or class, it is also possible to mock the ready method of the instance. This instance will satisfy the entire `Document` interface